# Create a barcode popup

Tags: excel, vba, code128

I need to create barcodes in Excel. For the ID in every row of the data I want to create a barcode.
The code should only get displayed when I click on the ID cell.
The code should get **displayed in a popup window**, so I can scan it from the screen.
To create the barcodes I think to use the Font Code 128, if possible.

How to create this popup?

Can one do it with user forms? Or is there something simpler? (one can not use the font code 128 in a textbox, it is not available there)

I know only some basics in VBA coding.

For now I don't need VBA code, but a simple advice what to do.

[image]

Comment: You can use several internet online services passing the code you want to generate, grab the result with XMLHTTP and finally display it on the 'PopUp'.

Comment: @ALeXceL my problem is the popup, not so much to create the barcode, because the font code 128 serves my needs well.

Comment: Ok. So, put code on the Selection_Change event of the worksheet, that evaluate if the Target variable of the event is intersecting the desired Range. If so, then show the Userform. The Userform should have a 'countdown' routine to unload it after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID Cell will be part of the range to be monitored by the Worksheet_SelectionChange event (in this example I defined this range as B2:B30)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B30")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTarget = Target
        Call fnSplashScreen_Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in your UserForm, here named frmSS (a splashscreen-like userform), add a Label, here named lblCode128, formatting its font as Code 128 Regular (this is the font name here), and choose an adequate font size (here I tested ok for '36'). You'll have to resize the label dimensions to achieve a good one.

The suggested code to put in a module is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public rngTarget As Excel.Range
Const intSecondsToShow As Integer = 5

Sub fnSplashScreen_Show()
    Application.OnTime Now, "fnSplashScreen_Close"
    Do
        DoEvents
        Load frmSS
        frmSS.lblCode128 = rngTarget.Value
        frmSS.Show
    Loop Until True
End Sub

Sub fnSplashScreen_Close()
    Dim datWaitTime As Date
    datWaitTime = TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + intSecondsToShow)
    Application.Wait datWaitTime
    On Error Resume Next
    Unload frmSS
End Sub
```

These two routines deal with the Wait method delaying the unload of the Userform for 5 seconds (see Const intSecondsToShow)

Comment: This is great! Thank you a lot! This makes things sooo easy for me.  What is the "Do Loop... until True" good for?

Comment: do you have experience with font code 128 in Excel? One needs a macro to display the barcode. I tried a vba code but it is not working. Is it so that there are different developers of that font code 128 and the vba code to create the string only works with a particular developers font code? (I don't know the developer of our font code 128 and which VBA code to use)

Comment: Oops! You can strip the Do/Loop out of the code! (I copied it from another one that used it for other purposes)

Comment: I used this https://www.dafont.com/code-128.font. It was necessary to reboot the machine to take effect. I have one code to create the barcode under Excel/VBA (EAN13)

Comment: Where did you get the vba code from? I can't find it on that website.

Comment: I have this VBA code in my backups. I adapted to suit your needs. The link I posted is only for downloading the TTF font. As I said, after saving this TTF file in C:\Windows\Fonts\ it was necessary to restart the machine. After rebooting, the font is displayed in the font names. Excel uses it to format the text box font display. Did you run the userform successfully? Did it show the barcode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247599/discussion-between-alexcel-and-prema).